# How to solve the errror "image not found"?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-universal-app, assetslibrary

I am working on universal project(iPhone/iPad), in which the code that I used is same on iphone and ipad. The code is working well in iphone and not working in iPad.

It returns the following error.

> dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary
>     Referenced from: /Users/mac/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.2/Applications/AFE91FFD-27A4-41A9-B5AF-C4336F10A9F3/Move On Inspirational Quotes.app/Move On Inspirational Quotes
>     Reason: image not found

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this error.

Comment: Check this link , may be it will be of help to you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373730/how-to-add-image-from-photo-library-or-camera-to-my-ipad-application

Comment: Are you using the UIPopoverviewController?

Comment: @neonsamuel I am not using UIPopoverviewController.

Comment: @neonsamuel I don't see how it would even be relevant. The problem is that the iPad runs a version of iOS that doesn't have the AssetsLibrary framework (at least not among the public ones).

Comment: @Gill that question is also completely irrelevant. These "images" are not pictures. These the memory images of the used dynamic libraries that are searched for symbols by the dynamic loader upon application startup.

Comment: @neonsamuel my ipad simulator is 3.2, does Assets library work on this target

Comment: @H2CO3 the error corresponds to the question so maybe...

Comment: @iPhone_suren nope, AssetsLibrary is iOS 4.0+.

Comment: @Gill That error **does not correspond to this question in any way.** The OP of the question you linked gets an `unrecognized selector` error due to failing to properly present the UIPopoverController. Here the OP experiences crashes caused by the dynamic linker. These are two completely different errors.

Comment: @H2CO3 hmmm i get your point ....

Comment: Thank you to all. hope this works on ios4.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the AssetsLibrary framework is present only on iOS 4.0 and later, trying to run an application that uses it on earlier (i. e. 3.XX) iOSes will result in a crash. Either try eliminating the use of this framework from your application, or move on and support iOS 4.0 and later *only.*