# How to implement Take photo or Choose from gallery options in ios

Tags: ios, iphone

Can anyone help me to implement a functionality --> Take photo or Choose from gallery options,  when camera option is selected in app.

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-camera-iphone-app/

Comment: you need code in objective c or swift ?

Comment: What you have tried/searched/googled so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373730/how-to-add-image-from-photo-library-or-camera-to-my-ipad-application

Comment: yes i need to code in objective c. I have tried by implementing a view with two button to take pic and choose from gallery. Is there  any other methods to bring those buttons when the camera options is selected in app.

Comment: I have done this. I want to show the buttons(take picture or use gallery) when camera option is selected. Can u please help me for that

Answer (score 16, accepted):

// For taking image by camera

```
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

// For picking image from gallery

```
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

// for output image

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    // output image
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.profileImageView.image = chosenImage;
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Don't forget to add UIImagePickerControllerDelegate and UINavigationControllerDelegate.

Comment: I have done this. I want to show the buttons(take picture or use gallery) when camera option is selected. Can u please help me for that.

Comment: you can use `UIActionsheet` to do that. on your button tap open actionsheet with two options camara or photo library. refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223210/creating-uiactionsheet to learn how to use action sheet. open camara on camara button of actionsheet and same for photo library

Comment: you seems to be new iOS developer. just you need to customize by yourself. discuss with your team for that UI. No one can help for this kind of this kind of questions.